# Size limit of local folder?

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

My C#/XAML WinRT app makes use of `ApplicationData.LocalFolder` to store data. I'm wondering if there's any size limit for this folder. I didn't find any information on the web/MSDN... Is this folder limited in size or not?

Comment: In terms of what? For size, it would be the amount of free space you have. For items there might be filesystem limit.

Comment: E.g. Silverlight has a quota for the IsolatedStorage folder. Is there anything for a Windows Store App, too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can read in the documentation available at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx:

> There are no general size restriction on local data stored.

Comment: Accordingly to the very same article LocalFolder data is backed up to the cloud so technically there should be at least an indirect limit by the size of OneDrive. Am I right?