# Local storage limit Windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone

Is there a limit on the amount of localstorage that an application can use in windows phone 8.1?

I am logging at every instance of the application run and after a few days of running, when i retrieve the logs, i see that half of the log is corrupted.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size limit of local folder?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12857077/size-limit-of-local-folder)

Comment: It there was a storage limit, then you would hit an exception, not data corruption. It's likely that there's a bug in your logging code. Given the symptoms, I'd say: 1/ Make sure you flush and close your streams properly, 2/  Make your code threadsafe

Comment: i did hit a storage exception too. Here's the exception,

Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)